# Modify the contents of php.ini in my Dockerfile

Tags: linux, command-line, php, docker, php.ini

I'm using containers which run php environments and in my Dockerfile I set php.ini from the development template

```
cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

then once the container is ready I open the file with a text editor and modify a few lines (memory limit, max upload size, etc.)

**Can I edit those lines from the command line (from the Dockerfile) while still using the default template from docker hub as a base?**

(The idea would be to avoid keeping and mounting an updated local copy of the file from my host).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new docker container and edit the file in that Dockerfile:

```
FROM whatevercontaineryoucurrentlyuse:latest

RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini && \
    sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize = 20M/upload_max_filesize = 128M/g' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini && \
    sed -i 's/whatever_option = 1234/whatever_option = 4321/g' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

Once you have this Dockerfile, create the new container with:

`docker build -t yournewcontainername:latest .`